# Why can't I access a variable declared in a class, which implements a Java interface, from Scala?

Tags: java, scala, interface, scope

In Java I have a class that implements an interface:

```
AlertDialog implements DialogInterface
```

If some variables are declared inside of the interface I could access them:

```
AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE
```

But in Scala the above line does not compile. Seems like it is hidden. Is there any way to access these variables in Scala without creating a new object or doing anything else hacky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in Scala to have access to these variables from the `AlertDialog` class but you could use the interface itself as an object to access them.

So you can directly access the variables from the interface:

```
DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE
```

Comment: wait a minute. you post a question **AND** an answer at the same time??

Comment: @UmNyobe This is a perfectly fine thing to do. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: you can answer your own question. that's fine. Put posting a question and an answer at the same is troublesome. Plus he answers as if he was a different person :).

Comment: I don't think it is troublesome at all. SO is a question & answer site. If you have a question about a problem that anyone else could face (or even yourself, in the future) then posting it along with an answer can only be beneficial. Plus you get other potential alternate solutions in the process. See it as a self-documentation effort, that could happen to help others. See also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: that is perfectly fine and encuraged: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @Arjan nice, will remember this.

Comment: Yep just to be part of the conversation, I found out the solution and as stackoverflow points out, sharing knowledge is good! And I believe sharing code in a Q&A form is better than a simple snippet! And yes! You are most welcome to provide alternate better answers! I think stackoverflow expects you so because I cannot declare my answer as the correct solution unless a two day period has passed

Answer (score 14):

To give slightly more detail: the reason these can't be accesed is that George is talking about static members defined on the interface. Scala doesn't have static members - instead, one creates an `object`, which is a regular class with a single implementation. When you're extending from a Java interface, Scala will extend only the non-static members, because the static ones are treated as being in a companion `object`.  The companion object is named the same as the interface, so you can access it as `DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE`.